# Does this scenario call for a Factory Pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns, yii, yii2

I have a `Model` which can be created across different controllers or classes. An example of this is the scenario that `AController` may need to create the model using the same logic in `ModelController`. Some facts about creating this model are thus:

- it does not depend on any other model in my domain space.
- it contains more logic than the usual `(new Model($params))->save()`

Does this call for a `ModelFactory` or is it okay to duplicate the code? How do I go about this?

I know this calls for some sort of abstraction; but which exactly?

#### EDIT:

I have a `Car` model and a `Driver` model which both have their controllers each and a create action respectively. However, in the `RaceController#actionRegistration`, a `Car` and a `Driver` can be created. The processes required to create both models are not the vanilla `Car#create()`. Will the creation process in the `RaceController#actionRegister()` require I use a Factory pattern? Note: I cannot redirect from `RaceController#actionRegister()` to the other create actions. I want to have both models created here.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. doesn't a controller represent the scope here where model instances should be created then destroyed as soon as a response did solve that request ? 'contains more logic than the usual' can't be solved by class inheritance (like [this](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/ar-single-table-inheritance.md)) ? or within a run function and pre set configs within `Yii::createObject($config)` ? or is it about [Immutable objects](https://ragazzo.github.io/immutability/oop/2016/05/03/immutability.html) ? do you have any use case ?

Comment: @SalemOuerdani please check the edit in the question

Comment: If you can create a Car and a Driver independently of each other, then why can you not just use Car#create() and Driver#create() in the RaceController#actionRegister()?

Comment: Because those are controller actions

Answer (score 1):

This answer your question: How do I go about this?

In the Factory pattern, the simple factory is often declared statically (as is the case in Larry Ullman’s book), but in the Factory Method pattern, the factoryMethod() method is declared as an abstract one that can be overridden. The reason for that is flexibility.

[image: Factory Method Class Diagram]

1. Client wants a product.
2. The client MUST request the product through the factory method.
3. Remember this OOP rule: A class should only have a single responsibility.
4. Factory class must not contain anything other than the creation of objects
5. In the rest of the code, we do not need to create objects directly, only through the factory
6. In the factory, you can use the static method, it will save from the creation of the factory object, but will prevent further inheritance class.

Your client (i.e. protected/views/products/**index.php**)

```
<?php
include("../models/Pizza.php");
include("../models/PizzaEurope.php");
include("../models/PizzaItaly.php");

include("Order.php");

include("FactoryPizza.php");

$order = new Order();
$order->orderPizza('PizzaEurope');
```

In your controller:

```
<?php
class OrderController extends Controller {
  private $_pizza;

  public function orderPizza($type) {
    $pizza = new FactoryPizza();
    $this->_pizza = $pizza->create($type);
    echo $this->_pizza->getTitle(). ' - ' .$this->_pizza->getCost();
  }
}
```

In FactoryClass:

```
<?php 
  class FactoryPizza {
  public function create($type) {
    switch($type) {
        case 'PizzaEurope':
            $pizza = new PizzaEurope();
            break;
        case 'PizzaItaly':
            $pizza = new PizzaItaly();
            break;
    }
    return $pizza;
 }
}
```

This was a simple example, and I hope it illustrates design pattern concepts that might be useful. You can find another example [here](http://www.php5dp.com/a-simple-php-design-pattern-the-factory-method/)